# How to implementing SSL pinning in ionic 3

Tags: ssl, ionic3

Iam new in Ionic 3 and i want to implement SSL pinning in my application. I am using this plugins https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/ and my home.ts looks like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {HTTP} from '@ionic-native/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http:HTTP) {

  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
this.load();
  }
load(){
    this.http.get('https://www.dashboard.mambowallet.com', {}, {})
  .then(data => {
    console.log("connection successful");
    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.data); // data received by server
    console.log(data.headers);

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("connection not successful");
    console.log(error.status);
    console.log(error.error); // error message as string
    console.log(error.headers);

  });
}
}
```

And my `app.modules.ts` looks like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import {HTTP} from '@ionic-native/http';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    HTTP,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have saved the server SSL certificate at the src/assets folder and when i do ionic serve, on the browser the console outputs this

[image: Error]

Am I missing something?

Comment: what happens when you simply do `console.log(error);`

Comment: console.log(error); outputs "cordova_not_available"

Comment: ohk.. it uses cordova plugin for http.. cordova is not supported with `ionic serve` unless you are using ionic devapp.. Use emulator/device to test this

Comment: yes has now worked on the phone. Thanks @SurajRao but i still have a  problem. If i change the url to something like "https://www.facebook.com" it still prints 'connection successful' yet i do not have the SSL certificate for Facebook. why or how can i restrict it to only communicate to the server whose certificate is stored in the assets folder?

Answer (score 1):

You need to test on a real device. You won't be able to use any cordova or native plugin within Chrome browser/emulator i.e. you cannot use "ionic serve"

Run this command below and use Safari to debug your app.

```
ionic cordova run ios --device  -l --debug --verbose
```